# Battle between Shiva and Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, shiva, shiva-purana

I am following the mega serial [Dev ke dev Mahadev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devon_Ke_Dev...Mahadev). In an episode they are showing a battle between Shiva and Vishnu. Is this true? or It is cheap attempt by the show just to increase their TRP?

Comment: A battle did take place,fierce and almost never ending and without anyone emerging as winner at the end.